# onSaveInstanceState in Fragment not working?

Tags: android, screen-rotation, savestate

I need help.I don't know what is wron here.Need Saved Instance Data in fragment but it's not working for me? Can anyone help ? Here is my code:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Log.e(getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName(),"DATA is NULL");
        }else{
            Log.e(getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName(),"DATA IS NOT NULL " + savedInstanceState.getString(Constans.SAMPLEDATA));
        }


@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable(Constans.MOVIE, movie);
        outState.putString(Constans.SAMPLEDATA, "sampleData");
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling `super.onSaveInstanceState()` in the Activity that handles he Fragment?

Comment: how you know that it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because on screen rotate your activity gets recreated so does the fragment inside it start from initial position again as it was started on activity first launch

You need to add this in onCreate of your activity and set the fragment inside if statement like this example

```
if (savedInstanceState == null){

        launchfragment

    } else {

        // do nothing
    }
```

hope this helps

Comment: it has nothing to do with the stated problem

Answer (score 0):

Add  ***super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);***

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelable(Constans.MOVIE, movie);
    outState.putString(Constans.SAMPLEDATA, "sampleData");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: why there are two super calls?

Comment: it's not working for me.I wrote this but nothing is happen.